# SDDM login screen Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login

**Configuration**

```
Ubuntu 18.04
"KDE Plasma5 Workspaces" as desktop environment in Active directory
SDDM login screen
```

**Problem**

Ubuntu login screen default settings.

AD logins works and is fine. Is it possible to modify SDDM login screen to show empty username & pass or last **AD** username. By default it`s shows local username and not empty login or last AD user. User must click on Different User button every time to log in. Any idea how to modify greeter. Did try to google it with no success. Did try to install various themes it does not help.

**EDIT**

Maybe there is other greeter more flexible so it can display empty fields? I did try lightdm with no sucess. Sure I`m missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your UIDs start at 10000 (not counting system users). The range from 10000 on is typically used for non-local users. Then the following in `/etc/sddm.conf` should help:

```
[Users]
MaximumUid=9999
```

Note that UIDs of local users typically start at 1000, so if those also shall be hidden, then use `MaximumUid=999`.

You can also add

```
RememberLastUser=false
RememberLastSession=false
```

to this section to get rid of some more artifacts.

Comment: Unfortunately these settings have no effect.

Comment: Is it still showing users with UID 10000 or greater?

Comment: Actually this config works only not  MaximumUid, but MinimumUid!!!

Comment: Then I guess the relevant UIDs are below 10000 on your system. Did you check?

Comment: I think the setting applies to specified user UID (from AD ) and they have UID  way over 10000. So correct setting will be MinimumUid, but thank`s  a lot Your suggestion helped.

Comment: I read again. You want to hide *local* users. They have probably UIDs in the range 1000-9999. Then the right config would be `MaximumUid=999`. This will hide local and AD users.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a long-standing Fedora bug (from 2015 up until Fedora 30 this May) with a similar question:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1238889